# How do you download multiple indicators into separate columns in R from World Bank API?

Tags: r, api

I am downloading the values of a few indicators from the World Bank database using its API (package `wbstats`). Using this chunk of code I get every indicator into a new set of rows. However, I want to download data into separate columns by indicators.

```
library(wbstats)

credit_vars <- wbsearch(pattern = "GDP", extra = TRUE, 
                        fields = c("indicator", "indicatorDesc"))

# Downloading data - 9 countries, 7 indicators
credit_data <- wb(country = c("DEU", "FRA","ESP", "GBR", "ITA", 
                  "POL", "SWE", "NOR", "FIN"), indicator = c("FB.AST.NPER.ZS",
                  "GFDD.AI.15", "FM.AST.OFIN.CN", "FS.AST.PRVT.GD.ZS", "GFDD.SI.07", 
                  "GFDD.OI.04", "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD"), mrv = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using `wbstats` package, use parameter `return_wide = TRUE` within the `wb()` function.

Sometimes it is better to check for documentation first, using wb, as people write these functions and packages user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is more of a problem of how to transform the data once its out of the API - using data.table, you can reshape this data pretty easily!

Using the mrv (most recent value) returns lots of gaps in the dates, so I changed your example to return a date window.  This returns a dataset with less gaps across groups.

```
credit_data <- wb(country = c("DEU", "FRA","ESP", "GBR", "ITA", 
                              "POL", "SWE", "NOR", "FIN"),
                  indicator = c("FB.AST.NPER.ZS",
                                                                         "GFDD.AI.15", "FM.AST.OFIN.CN", "FS.AST.PRVT.GD.ZS", "GFDD.SI.07", 
                                                                         "GFDD.OI.04", "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD"), 
                  startdate = '2014', enddate = '2019')
library(data.table)
setDT(credit_data)
credit_data_wide = dcast(credit_data, date + iso2c + country ~indicator, value.var = 'value')
```